How do I get the JetBrains Mono font to work in Visual Studio Code?
I have installed the JetBrains Mono font on the computer (Windows11) and in vsc I have changed the font to JetBrains Mono and it worked. The next day I open Visual Studio Code again and this time it appears with the previous source and not with JetBrains Mono. For it to work I have to reinstall the font but the same thing happens to me again. How can i fix this?
